# Windows 7, TrueCrypt and Sleep - automount when resuming machine

Tags: windows-7, sleep, truecrypt

Is there a way to get a TrueCrypt container to mount automatically when resuming from Windows 7 Sleep? I have the container saved on my system disk, it's not on a separate external hard drive. The password is cached in memory (which I know adds extra vulnerability). Once Windows comes up, I have to go into TrueCrypt and select 'Mount Favorites'. Any way of getting this to happen automatically?

Comment: Doesn't automatic mounting kind of defeat the purpose of an encrypted volume?

Comment: I see your point. However, a user would still have to enter the pass-phrase when logging in to Windows. I would even be OK entering the TC pass-phrase when coming out of Sleep each time, but it doesn't even attempt to mount the volumes. The primary reason I'm encrypting the disks is if they are stolen (particularly the external drive).

Answer (score 1):

I think this might get you what you want:

http://www.wikihow.com/Mount-Truecrypt-Volumes-at-Login-Before-Other-Programs-Start